# How to download a pushed Odoo release and upload to Github

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, odoo

To give a bit background information on whats going on, few months back the company I'm employed with purchased Odoo ERP system and did a couple of custom modifications to it using a third party company. After the development developers pushed the code into a GCP VM instance. However my company was not using this release at all. 6 months after management wants to remove the existing GCP VM and transfer the source code of Odoo into Github to save the infrastructure cost.But I have absolutely no idea how to do this as I'm not coming from an infrastructure background. I can see a VM sitting in GCP with below specification.

Machine type: custom (8 vCPUs, 16 GB memory)
Reservation: Automatically choose
CPU platform: Intel Haswell
Zone: us-central1-a
Operating system: Ubuntu

It would be really helpful if someone can point me at the correct direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub is for hosting program sources only. You cant run your odoo from there. You may migrate to odoo.sh (And code to GitHub)

You need access to your modifications, source code, and database files. Then you can upload your source to GitHub. After that, buy an instance to odoo.sh and upload your database backup there.

And if you are interested in how to get files from GCE, then there should be information for it:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files

Comment: Hi @Paxmees,

Thank you for your response, yes thats correct all we want is to store our Odoo code within GitHub. Until we decide where we want to host that again :)